# What is the difference between these two SSB phasing method block diagram?

Tags: communication

I was searching the block diagram of SSB phase shifting method. I found these two different block diagram:

[image: First diagram]
[image: Second diagram]

I thought the second one is wrong but this one is used many times in different websites. I tried to find the output signal by using trigonometric functions (The first equation is for first diagram, the second one is for second diagram):

[image: The equations that i used]

Are my equations mathematically wrong? And do these diagrams generate exactly same SSB waveform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given the output of each equation has (Wc + Waa), then the phasor is the same.

With -sin (x) being the same waveform as cos(X) except for TIME SHIFTING, I think you have shown equivalence.

================================

The waveforms will be sinusoids, with 90 degrees of timeshift.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I mean, are they exactly same waveforms?